# Which Glue for Refrigerator Door

Tags: adhesive, polyurethane

Our refrigerator has two little nubs built into the door that holds the butter door on.  One of the two nubs cracked off, exposing the insulating foam underneath.  I was going to use a super glue variant on it until I read the package which states not to use it on foam.  Which glue is best to use in this situation?

[image: Broken nub with exposed foam.]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of where this pulled out from? And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An epoxy may be your best choice for a problem such as this. Most epoxies do not react with foam products. On the negative side, cold temperatures are not conducive to good bonds, which may result in days or weeks of cure time if the refrigerator is in use.

Even though you reference not using a CA type of glue, you'd be applying it to the plastic surfaces and not to the foam. You would have no strength by applying adhesive to the foam regardless of your selection.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djtKXkTqPUI

The above video shows a series of tests performed on plastic being attached to steel, using various types of epoxies and a couple of CA glues. The winner, in my opinion, is the Loctite Gel Control Super Glue. I've used this product and it's easy to apply exactly where needed.

You would be able to avoid applying it to the foam and even a bit of overflow would cause no problem. If you want to ensure no contact, consider to apply a layer of ordinary wood (or paper) glue aka PVA glue to the foam (only) to seal the surface, but I think that's overkill.

Another super glue type adhesive with which I've had success is DAP Rapid Fuse, which is a bit more expensive, but good product often costs more.

If you absolutely have to avoid CA glues, it appears from the video that the old standby, JB Weld may have sufficient strength. I can attest that it's strong stuff and has worked well for me in the past.

Comment: Fred, thank you for your reply.  I tried the Loctite product you mentioned and it appears to have worked perfectly.